# GraphQL java - using SourceLocations to extract the field from a ValidationError

Tags: spring-boot, graphql-java, graphql-spring-boot

Supposing I have a simple GraphQL schema:

```
type Query {
  test(requestId: String!): String
}
```

and I execute a query like this (intentionally passing a Number instead of a String as 'requestId' value):

```
query {
 test(requestId: 5)
}
```

Then I have a Java snippet where I execute the query manually:

```java
// code

ExecutionInput executionInput = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
  .query(query)
  .variables(variables)
  .build();

ExecutionResult executionResult = graphQL.execute(executionInput);

if (!executionResult.getErrors().isEmpty()) {
  GraphQLError error = executionResult.getErrors().get(0);

  if (error instanceof ValidationError validationError) {
    // Extract the field in error here (maybe with SourceLocations from "validationError" obj)
  }
}

// code
```

I expect to get a ValidationError, and I get it but this is his content:

```
ValidationError{validationErrorType=WrongType, queryPath=[test], message=Validation error of type WrongType: argument 'requestId' with value 'IntValue{value=5}' is not a valid 'String' @ 'test', locations=[SourceLocation{line=2, column=8}], description='argument 'requestId' with value 'IntValue{value=5}' is not a valid 'String''}
```

the content of `validationError.getSourceLocations().get(0).getSourceName()` is null!

---

Is possible to get the name of the field who has not passed the validation (in this case `requestId`)?

I'm able to create a `Document` object doing something like this:

```java
Document document = new Parser().parseDocument(query);
```

Maybe is possible to interpolate `SourceLocations` with the `Document` in order to retrieve the "failed field".

I tried a lot of stuff but without luck, maybe someone has faced the same before.

Comment: Is the field name not in validationError.getSourceLocations().get(0).getSourceName()? I will check later today.
Obviously if the validation error comes from multiple fields, you would need to loop through the sourceLocations.

Comment: Thanks for the help! No, when I inspect the validationError, via debugger, the `.getSourceName()` returns null!

Comment: That does not seem normal to me. I never had a problem getting the faulty field in the error. You could try to use the debugger to put a breakpoint when the ValidationError is created to understand why the SourceLocations is empty. Also, what's the full content of the validationError (message, description, validationErrorType, queryPath, extensions)?

Comment: @AllirionX I added more in the question, let me know if you want other data :)